# Grails Override embedded attributes mapping

Tags: grails, jpa, grails-orm

When working with a legacy existing database, we should be able to override embedded objects mapping for such a use case :
I want to add a customer in my database, this customer has 2 phones in the DB :
cu_phone1 and cu_phone2.
Given the following phone Object :

```
class Phone
{ String number [...] }
```

And the Customer:

```
class Customer { 
    Phone phone1 
    Phone phone2 
}
```

Actually, we can not map this model with gorm, because the Customer class cannot override the phone number mapping so that phone1.number is mapped to cu_phone1 in db and phone2.number is mapped to cu_phone2 in db.

With JPA, there is an annotation allowing to do so :

```
@AttributeOverride(name="number", column=@Column(name="cu_phone1")
Phone phone1
@AttributeOverride(name="number", column=@Column(name="cu_phone2")
Phone phone2
```

It would be great to have this feature in grails with gorm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would map like this:

```
class Customer { 
    Phone phone1 
    Phone phone2 

    static mapping = {
        columns {
            phone1 column: 'cu_phone1'
            phone2 column: 'cu_phone2'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use mapping to specify the column name like so:

```
static mapping = { column = "cu_phone1" }
```

to map the property to the column.  Is this what you're after or am I misunderstanding the question?

[Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html)

Answer (score -1):

If Phone have two attributes ?

```
class Phone
{ String number 
  String type
[...] }
```

And you want column name's :

```
  phone1.number : 'cust_number1'
  phone1.type : 'cust_type1'
  phone2.number : 'cust_number2'
  phone2.type : 'cust_type2'
```

?

Comment: That is a question, not an answer. Please write what would you do in the case you have described.